# Bind element to inner UserControl data context

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

As the title implies, I'm trying to bind an element to inner usercontrol data context, but it's a bit complicated.

First of all, here is a snippet of my xaml view:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" TabStripPlacement="Top"
            Style="{StaticResource TabControlStyle}" FontSize="16">
        <TabItem Header="Local Settings" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=localSettings, Path=IsEnabled}">
            <tabViews:LocalSettingsView x:Name="localSettings" DataContext="{Binding TabsVM, Converter={StaticResource dictionaryToViewModel}, ConverterParameter={x:Static enums:TabsEnum.LocalSettings}}" />
        </TabItem>
        ... more TabItems ...
    </TabControl>
```

As you can see, I've tried (without any luck) to bind it with element name, but it didn't work as expected.
I'm getting this exception in output window:
`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsEnabled' property not found on 'object' ''LocalSettingsView' (Name='localSettings')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsEnabled; DataItem='LocalSettingsView' (Name='localSettings'); target element is 'TabItem' (Name=''); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')`
Here are the relevant code sections:
**Binded property**

```
private Dictionary<string, ITabViewModel> _tabsVM;
    public Dictionary<string, ITabViewModel> TabsVM
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tabsVM == null)
            {
                _tabsVM = new Dictionary<string, ITabViewModel>()
                {
                    { "Network", new NetworkViewModel() },
                    { "Cru", new CRUViewModel() },
                    { "LocalSettings", new LocalSettingsViewModel() },
                    { "Connectivity", new ConnectivityViewModel() },
                    { "Security", new SecurityViewModel() },
                };
            }
            return _tabsVM;
        }
    }
```

**Converter**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {                        
        Dictionary<string, ITabViewModel> _tabsVM = value as Dictionary<string, ITabViewModel>;
        if (_tabsVM == null)
            return null;

        string param = Enum.GetName(typeof(TabsEnum), parameter);

        ITabViewModel _selectedVM;
        bool success = _tabsVM.TryGetValue(param, out _selectedVM);
        if (success)
            return _selectedVM;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

and finally, **TabsEnum**

```
    public enum TabsEnum
{
    LocalSettings,
    Network,
    Connectivity,
    Security,
    Cru,
}
```

### Edit

I'm adding the LocalSettingsView & it's ViewModel relevant part

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContentTemplateTest.Views.TabViews.LocalSettingsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ContentTemplateTest;component/Styles/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Hospital Name" />
        <TextBox x:Name="hospitalTextBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="DEMO - 000000" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Full Address" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Department" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Date and Time" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DateAndTime}" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Interface Language" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInterfaceLang}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="Manual Language" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedManualLang}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Text="Units" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Units}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUnit}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Text="Video Settings" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding VideoSettings}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVideoFormat}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Text="Keyboard Input Language" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKeyboardLang}"/>            
    </Grid>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>            
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="50">
            <Image Source="../../src/Save.png" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="20" />
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="50">
            <Image Source="../../src/Cancel.png" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="20" />
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="50">
            <Image Source="../../src/Export.png" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="20" />
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

and the relevant property:

```
        public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
```

**How can I achieve my goal?**
Thanks!

Comment: The exception is about a binding for `IsValid`. There's nothing about `IsValid` in any of the XAML or C# you included. Can you include the binding that produced the exception, with context?

Comment: Oh, I missed that. The IsValid is the changed IsEnabled property. I thought that maybe IsEnabled is somehow preserved and causing the fault. There isn't much in the inner ViewModel, just the property IsEnabled returning false

Comment: Can you share the C# code for LocalSettingsView?

Comment: @EdPlunkett - changes were made. Nothing meaningful I think.

Comment: You must be leaving something out. That binding should work. UserControl has an IsEnabled property. I created a TabItem containing a named UserControl, bound the the TabItem's IsEnabled property to the user control's IsEnabled property via ElementName, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple solution.
Just move to DataContext to the TabItem

```
<TabItem Header="Local Settings" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" 
                 DataContext="{Binding TabsVM, Converter={StaticResource dictionaryToViewModel}, ConverterParameter={x:Static enums:TabsEnum.LocalSettings}}" >
            <tabViews:LocalSettingsView />
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Oh, you were trying to bind to the `IsEnabled` property of the *viewmodel* of `localSettings`. Why didn't you say that?

Comment: LOL that was my first guess, but then I thought you meant something else: http://imgur.com/a/U6Git